# pycharm skips first line in loop

Tags: python, pycharm

new to python and pycharm.  seeing something weird:

```
while condition:
    if thing.hasState():
        return thing
    dosomestufftothingwithrecursion
```

stepping through the execution goes from the while condition to the dostuff skipping over the test.  if I move the if below the dostuff it is called.

I'm assuming this is either pycharm glitch or python whitespace weirdness but not sure what to look for.

I don't need the issue solved just some hints on what I should be looking for or if this is an issue with pycharm potentially.

thanks,
/m

Comment: more code please? i use pycharm almost explicitly and have never had an issue that was ide related

Comment: What do you mean "I don't need the issue solved"?! Do you understand how this community works?

Comment: @AlexThornton poorly phrased but I think it's pretty obvious what they mean. "Don't give me the solution, point out the problem."

Comment: You need to provide some actual code.